# Issue querying a materialized view redshift

Tags: database, amazon-redshift

I've created a materialized view in redshift as follows:

```
create materialized view stats as
select *
from t1
```

however when i try to query it:

```
select * from stats
```

I get this error:
`[2022-06-26 15:09:35] [XX000] ERROR: Failed assertion at rewriteHandler.c:883 - CheckMvInternalTables(mv_id). invalid MV internal tables.`

I can't find anything on the internet about this so I'm a bit at a loss. Any clues on where i can go with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
Set AutoRefresh to ON on the mv (as it defaults to off). Or manually trigger the refresh.